# acceder a una posicion en un json en php sin saber tu nombre

Tags: php, json

soy nuevo en JSON y php mi duda es la siguiente:

como accedo a esto `echo($resultado['empleados']['nombre'])`

solamente con la posicion, deberia de salir asi: `echo($resultado[0][0])`

, pero me devuelve un `null`

este es el codigo:(intentos realizados)

```
$data= '{"empleados": {{ "nombre":"Jorge" , "apellido":"Mesa", "edad":28 } }}';
$resultado = json_decode($data);

echo($resultado['empleados']['nombre'])//funciona
echo($resultado[0][0]) //No funciona pero deseo acceder con posiciones
```

Comment: Lo que intentas, no se puede, por que estas creando un objeto con esas propiedades (nombre, apellido....), intentar acceder a ellos con indices no vale, pues lo interpreta como propiedades y no las encuentra. Si lo que necesitas es acceder si o si con indices no crees un objeto, crea un array. O puedes crear las propiedades '0' '1' etc... y asignarles el valor, pero no seria muy logico.

Answer (score 0):

creo que se te fue una llave en el JSON, de cualquier forma necesitas parsear el JSON como un array de objetos, para hacerlo el método **json_decode** tiene el parámetro **assoc** que hace que regrese un array en lugar de un objeto, posteriormente necesitas poder acceder a la propiedad por indice, el método **array_values** te va a devolver todos los valores de ese nodo en un array con indices numéricos, de esta forma ya podrás acceder a los valores por medio de su posición, ejemplo:

```
<?php

$data= '{"empleados": { "nombre":"Jorge" , "apellido":"Mesa", "edad":28 }}';
$resultado = json_decode($data, true);

$nombre_by_prop = $resultado['empleados']['nombre'];
$nombre_by_index = array_values(array_values($resultado)[0])[0];

printf("%s\n", $nombre_by_prop);
printf("%s\n", $nombre_by_index);

?>
```

**Documentación**:

json_decode https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

array_values https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php